# Dynamically adding series, how to get rid of default y-axis?

Tags: highcharts

I'm dynamically adding series to my empty chart, by adding a serie I'm also adding a new axis to it using `addAxis` but when adding my first serie I always get two y-axis, one is my own and one is highcharts own default y-axis. Is there a way to disable auto-creation of this axis?

```
    init(): void {
        this.chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: this.chart,
                animation: Highcharts.svg,
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: this.x
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true
            }
        }

        $('#highchartcontainer').highcharts(this.chartOptions);
    }

    addSerie(tag: Tag): void {
        this.addSeries(new Array<Tag>(tag));
    }

    addSeries(tags: Tag[]): void {

        for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            let tag = tags[i];

            $('#highchartcontainer').highcharts().addAxis({
                id: i,
                title: {
                    text: tag.getTitle(),
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                max: tag.getMaxValue()
            });

            $('#highchartcontainer').highcharts().addSeries({
                turboThreshold: 0,
                name: tag.getId(),
                yAxis: i,
                data: (function () {
                    var tag_data = new Array<Point>();
                    for (var n = 0; n < tag.getData().length; n++) {
                        tag_data.push(new Point(tag.getData()[n].x, tag.getData()[n].y));
                    }
                    return tag_data;
                })()
            });
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVZnq.jpg

How do I get rid of yellow-marked y-axis?

Comment: you can set the visibility of the default one to false.

Comment: How can I control the properties of the default one?

Comment: Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n10nqdyb/)

Comment: Thanks, post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the visibility of the default one using the [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) should do the job.

```
 chart.yAxis[0].update({visible:false});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/n10nqdyb/) is the fiddle.

Comment: I want to add in my case: $('#highchartcontainer').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({visible:false});